# Creating a heatmap of coordinates using plotly or seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I have a dataframe consisting of 130,000 points which has a head like this:

`Latitude   Longitude
0    36.577570  36.578930
1    36.577634  36.578939
2    36.577574  36.578917
3    36.577639  36.578926
4    36.576966  36.583783`

I tried to create a heat map of these points using seaborn and matplotlib however I failed and I don't know what to do at this point. I am not required to plot these points on a real world map, I just need to create a regular heat map. If you guys could help that would be great, thanks a lot.

Comment: what kind of output do you expect?

Comment: Possibly you are looking for `plt.hist2d`?

Answer (score 0):

I used a regular 'heatmap' plot available from plotly.js. I think plotly is also available in python. I used the unique latitudes as the y dimension with values of the array sorted from 90..0..-90. And I used the longitudes as the x dimension with values of the array sorted from -180..0..180. Then the actual values for the heatmap should be stored in a 2D array where the first dimension is |y| and second dimension is |x|.

Please find the final JS code below:

```
var data = [
        {
            x: xvalues_arr,
            y: yvalues_arr,
            z: zvalues_arr,
            type: 'heatmap',
            connectgaps: true,
            hoverongaps: true
        }];
var layout = {
        title: '',
        annotations: [],
        autosize: true,
        margin: {
            l: 0,
            r: 0,
            t: 0,
            b: 0
        },
        hovermode: 'closest',
        xaxis: {
            ticks: '',
            ticksuffix: ' ',
            zeroline: false,
            showline: false,
            showgrid: false,
            showticklabels: false
        },
        yaxis: {
            ticks: '',
            ticksuffix: ' ',
            showticklabels: false,
            zeroline: false,
            showline: false,
            showgrid: false
        }
    };
    var config = {
        'displayModeBar': false,
        'responsive': true
    };

    Plotly.newPlot('world-map-env-data', data, layout, config);
```